# pandas : columns sample based on row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, split

For example I have this dataframe:

```
 d = {'data_1' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4., 1], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'class']),
  'data_2' : pd.Series([5., 6., 7., 8., 0], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'class']),
  'data_3' : pd.Series([9., 10., 11., 12., 1], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'class'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

so as output I get:

```
    data_1  data_2  data_3
a   1.0      5.0    9.0
b   2.0      6.0    10.0
c   3.0      7.0    11.0
cls 1.0      0.0    1.0
```

what I would like to do is to create a filter according to the values reported in "**cls**" row and split the data frame into two according to the two possible classes

```
    data_1  data_3
a   1.0      9.0
b   2.0      10.0
c   3.0      11.0
cls 1.0      1.0
```

and

```
        data_2
a        5.0
b        6.0    
c        7.0    
cls      0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc` - first for select all columns by condition and second for select row by `index`:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.loc['class'] == 1]
df2 = df.loc[:, df.loc['class'] == 0]
```

There is also possible create dicionary by all unique values of row `class`:

```
s = df.loc['class']
dfs = {k:df[v.index] for k, v in s.groupby(s)}
print (dfs)

{0.0:        data_2
a         5.0
b         6.0
c         7.0
d         8.0
class     0.0, 1.0:        data_1  data_3
a         1.0     9.0
b         2.0    10.0
c         3.0    11.0
d         4.0    12.0
class     1.0     1.0}
```

---

```
print (list(dfs.keys()))
[0.0, 1.0]

print (dfs[0])
       data_2
a         5.0
b         6.0
c         7.0
d         8.0
class     0.0:

print (dfs[1])
       data_1  data_3
a         1.0     9.0
b         2.0    10.0
c         3.0    11.0
d         4.0    12.0
class     1.0     1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it dynamically

```
In [889]: s = df.loc['class']

In [890]: dfs = {k: df[s[s==v].index] for k, v in  enumerate(s.unique())}

# or dfs = {v: df[s[s==v].index] for v in s.unique()} -- for value based keys

In [891]: dfs[0]
Out[891]:
       data_1  data_3
a         1.0     9.0
b         2.0    10.0
c         3.0    11.0
d         4.0    12.0
class     1.0     1.0

In [892]: dfs[1]
Out[892]:
       data_2
a         5.0
b         6.0
c         7.0
d         8.0
class     0.0
```